# On using this class augmentedDriver, it's launching unnecessary browser Instances

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, augmentor

I am using following code snipped to take screenshot in selenium 2.21.

```
augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
File scrnshot = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrnshot, new File(File_Name));
```

Whenever i call method containing this code, it's launching new browser instances with text "This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.
"

driver = new new InternetExplorerDriver();

Please let me know the issue, as well as solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this line:

```
augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
```

Starts new Driver instance. But you need to give here:

```
File scrnshot = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Not **augmentedDriver** but existing **driver instance**.